Spring Boot App return a request body but don't set the Content-Type header
Is it possible to configure Spring Boot to not set the Content-Type header?  I have a Spring Boot applictaion with a RestController that proxies requests to a legacy system.  The legacy system returns and XML body but does not return a Content-Type header.  If I setup my ResponseEntity object with the XML body but ensure that the headers don't contain a Content-Type header, when I inspect the response in Postman I can see that Spring has added a Content-Type header of text/plain charset=utf-8.  The legacy system should provide a Content-Type header but doesn't.  Is it possible to stop Spring setting the header value?

In your controller method inputs add HttpServletResponse response then set your content type . for setting content type you can use MediaType class too for example for json you can set MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

Thanks for the suggestion, but if no content type is set and the method returns a string, Spring adds text/plain as the Content-Type.
